# Adding an arrow to ag-grid agRichSelectCellEditor to make the drop-down feature more intuitive

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

At base, the agRichSelectCellEditor does not contain any indication that it is an actual drop-down, and I'd like to add a down arrow to cel display cell to make it more intuitive. I've searched through the docs and haven't found anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cellClass` property of the column definition to show an arrow symbol on the cell.

```
.drop-down-style {
  &::after {
    content: '\f0d7';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  }
}
```

In this example you need to have Font Awesome imported in your code. But custom css will also work. You can position the arrow also using css.

Set the css property like given below on the column definition of the required column.

```
{
  headerName: 'dropown column',
  cellClass: 'qft-select-cell'
}
```

Comment: In the event that the value within the cell is long enough to force the text-overflow ellipsis, the dropdown arrow gets crunched onto the second line. Any ideas about how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below cellRenderer works for me

```
      cellRenderer: function (params) {
    var eDiv = document.createElement('span');

    eDiv.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M5 8l4 4 4-4z"/></svg>' + params.value;
    return eDiv;
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).